# Node.js Request why is 400 response being caught in try catch

Tags: node.js, express, request, request-promise

I am making a http request to a backend. The request returns a 400 with a body telling me why it was a bad request.

But why is it being caught in the try catch, why is not being returned in 
metrics variable.

if i try the backend request directly in postman i can see the body response with the 400 status so the request is successful. I assumed requests are only caught if they are not successful.

```
 public async processMetrics(sessionId: any, side: any): Promise<any> {

        try {

                metrics = await this.getMetrics(session._id, sessionRequest._id);
                // Metrics not returned here               
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("CAUGHT 400");


        }

    }
```

--

```
public async getMetrics(sessionId: any, requestId: any): Promise<any> {

    const url = this.config.backendUrl + "/check/metrics";

    const options = {
        uri: url,
        headers: {
            "X-IDCHECK-SESSION_ID": sessionId,
        },
        body: {},
        json: true,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    };

    return request.get(options);

}
```

i am using the request package - 
https://github.com/request/request 
https://github.com/request/request-promise-native

Comment: "i can see the body response with the 400 status so the request is successful" A 400 response is [by definition an error](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request-promise` will reject if the status code is non-2xx. In order to avoid that, you have to pass `simple: false` as an option.

You can check this in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise#get-a-rejection-only-if-the-request-failed-for-technical-reasons)

```
var options = {
    uri: 'http://www.google.com/this-page-does-not-exist.html',
    simple: false    //  <---  <---  <---  <---
};

rp(options)
    .then(function (body) {
        // Request succeeded but might as well be a 404
        // Usually combined with resolveWithFullResponse = true to check response.statusCode
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Request failed due to technical reasons...
    });
```

> If the request fails completelty with no
>   response i still want that to be caught in the try catch

```
public async getMetrics(sessionId: any, requestId: any): Promise<any> {

    const url = this.config.backendUrl + "/check/metrics";

    const options = {
        uri: url,
        headers: {
            "X-IDCHECK-SESSION_ID": sessionId,
        },
        body: {},
        json: true,
        simple: false,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    };

    const response = await request.get(options);

    if(!response.body)
       throw new Error('Empty body');

    return response
}
```

Comment: Can i just confirm with you, if the request fails completelty with no response i still want that to be caught in the try catch.

Comment: adding `simple:false` did not work, the 400 bad response is still being caught in the try catch block.

Comment: Using simple false does work for 400 status code. So either you're using an old version or something else is happening. Show the stack trace.